# How to read a .docx file via PHP Word sample code in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, docx, phpword

Am trying to read a .docx file which is inside my project folder via PHP Word library. I have included autoloader like this :
`include_once  'vendor/autoload.php';`  in my controller.

**CODE FOR FUNCTION IN CONTROLLER:**

```
function test_phpword()
{
 $a=base_url();
 $path=$a."".'123.docx';
 $source =$path;

 echo date('H:i:s'), " Reading contents from `{$source}`";
 $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);

 echo write($phpWord, basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $writers);
}
```

**BUT GETTING ERROR LIKE BELOW:**

> 06:18:42 Reading contents from `http://localhost/myproject/123.docx`
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Cannot find archive file. in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/vendor/phpoffice/common/src/Common/XMLReader.php:51

Comment: Is it working on `doc` file type?

Comment: I tried now with a .doc file..Still error..

opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/vendor/phpoffice/common/src/Common/XMLReader.php on line 51.

Comment: I have same problem in `PHPExcel`. I wanna read `xlsx` file type. In Windows, it's working, but not in Ubuntu. But if I read `xls`, both works.

Comment: Okay..am getting some errors in 

../vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Reader/Word2007.php(145)..
But couldn't include in my question.

Comment: Are you able to edit the files inside PHPExcel library..it shows a lock symbol in all the folders of  Vendor folder...Is that same for you ?

Comment: Woww, you should do this : `sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject`. Maybe it caused by access permission

Comment: Yeah i got the permission .Thank you

Comment: Hi, did you get your problem solved. I still have the problem.

Comment: No. Still searching.....

Comment: i have this error? how to fix?

Comment: have you defined write function in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change

```
$path=$a."".'123.docx';
```

to

```
$path='123.docx';
```

And put 123.docx beside your php script file. make sure the two files are in the same place. Run your php script again.

If this helps and works fine you can check the file path and make proper change to your php program.

Answer (score 0):

While loading the path, you have to give relative path to the doc file as shown below,

```
$random_name = 123.docx;
$contents = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('../uploads/'.$random_name);
```

I don't know whats your `$base_url`, but it will not work if it is absolute path like `http://path/to/doc/file`.

I have worked on it and tested. Hope it helps.